# Deleted reference variable still pointing the old data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Are iterators refereces?? and if yes then why *listt* and *iteratorr* both have different ids and I can not mutate the *listt* object through *iterator*. Is *iteratorr* really  a reference to the listt object in my case?

```
listt=[1,2,3]
iteratorr=iter(listt)
listt[1]="a"
del listt
print(next(iteratorr))
print(next(iteratorr))
```

output

> 1

> a

Comment: "as it is mention in the theory…" Says who? That's plain wrong. An iterator is an iterator, Python doesn't even let you have pointers. Anything you can interact with in Python is, in the end, a PyObject, and not a pointer.

Comment: And in fact the iterator has a “reference” to the source data object, which keeps it in memory.  Nothing is ever removed by the garbage collector that is still in use.  ‘del’ removes a reference, not the underlying object, unless there are no references left.

Comment: Whoever is teaching you this is wrong. Completely wrong. In fact, anyone who uses the word "pointer" in a beginner Python course is wrong, for the same reason that anyone who uses the words "category theory" in a primary school course on fractions is wrong.

Comment: A list iterator has a reference to the list and a hidden index. Each time you call `next(iteratorr)` it returns `listref[index]` and then increments `index`, until `index` reaches `len(listref)`.

Answer (score 0):

A list iterator is roughly equivalent to the following class (the actual implementation is in C in CPython, you can find the code in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c, look for functions that begin with `listiter_` -- there are additional methods beside the ones I show).

```
class list_iter:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq
        self.index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index >= len(self.seq):
            raise StopIteration()
        result = self.seq[self.index]
        self.index += 1
        return result
```

`self.seq` contains a reference to the original list, not a copy. So if you modify the list in place, it will affect what the iterator returns.

`del listt` has no effect on this reference, it just removes the additional reference from the variable.